Custom Post type with a sub-URL under another Custom Post Type
I have some custom post types, which are cities.
These are located at /c/{postalcode}-{cityname}
Not I have some categories, which is a kind of filter "under" these cities - and the UX-flow is, that a customer goes to a city, and then choose a category.
These categories are located at the following URL today:
/category/{category-slug}
BUT - since they are a natural part of the "filtering" in the cities, I want them to be located under the cities URL-wise with a URL like this:
/c/{postalcode}-{cityname}/{category-slug}
Is it by any means possible to "place" a category under another custom post type in this manner? Or is it impossible?

Are you trying to achieve a similar effect as here - filter the custom post archive page by category or custom taxonomy?
